# Chrome Desktop Notification

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I use this code to push desktop notification to clients:

```
// Let's check if the browser supports notifications
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    toast(type, title, body);
}

// Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification(title, options);
}

// Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
        // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
        if (permission === "granted") {
            var notification = new Notification(title, options);
        } else {
            // toast(type, title, body);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is while Notification Setting is set to `Allowed` or `Default (Ask)` the browser doesn't show notification to client nor ask for permission.
regardless of the above code, when I type `Notification.permission` in chrome developer tools console it's `denined` (again, while it's set to `Allowed`)
the chrome version is 63.x.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've declined a notification, you don't get immediately prompted again. This is to keep sites from spamming the user.

This can be a problem during testing. Fortunately, if you open Chrome's notification settings you can remove the entry, which should allow you to go through a first-time visitor flow. Notification settings get moved from time to time, so you may have to poke around. My installed version, which is Chrome 60, has the notification settings at chrome://settings/content/notifications.